# Error during initialization of subgraph using Graph protocol

Tags: npm, graph, solidity, yarnpkg

I have a question here regarding The Graph indexing protocol. I am trying to initialize a subgraph but keep getting the error below. My npm version is 9.1.2, yarn version is 3.2.3, node version is 18.12.1, and graph version is 0.36.1.

> √ Fetching ABI from Etherscan
> √ Contract Name · NftMarketplace
> √ Index contract events as entities (Y/n) · true
> ———
> Generate subgraph
> Write subgraph to directory
> √ Create subgraph scaffold
> √ Initialize networks config
> √ Initialize subgraph repository
> × Failed to install dependencies: Command failed: yarn
>
> ```
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\@graphprotocol\graph-cli\node_modules\gluegun\build\index.js:13  
>     throw up;  
>      ^
> ```
>
> Error: Command failed: yarn
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:319:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {  
>    killed: false,  
>    code: 1,  
>    signal: null,  
>    cmd: 'yarn',  
>    stderr: ''  
> }
> ```

I have tried to downgrade the node version to v12.22.12 but still facing the same issue.

Comment: You say u're using node 18.12.1, but your logs say u're using 14.17.0. Since u're using nvm, try running `nvm use 18.12.1` and try again

Comment: @alephao I just managed to solve this issue and that was because there were both package.json and yarn.lock file in the upper directory 

Answer (score 2):

It is because of your NodeJs version. Try to use a NodeJs version below 18.
You can manage it using nvm (Node Version Manager).

I had the same error. It worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used NodeJs 16.